# How to lower QT Gui thread priority?

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, real-time

I am designing an embedded QT application in linux. Part of my application is a real-time audio stream that is the top priority of the system and has to always meet it's real time deadlines.  I have set this thread to be scheduled as FIFO with max priority:

```
schparam.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(),SCHED_FIFO, &schparam)
```

I need my QT GUI to always yield and let this real time process have priorty. So I tried setting QT GUI thread priorty as

```
QThread::currentThread()->setPriority(QThread::LowestPriority);
```

Yet this is still not working.  If I interact with the GUI for too long my real-time audio stream is xflowing.

Is there some other priority parameter I need to set here?  Unfortunately switching to a real-time kernel is not an option.

Comment: Have you tried setting the QThread::currentThread()'s priority using sched_priority instead of QThread's priority switcher?

Comment: Yes. Good thought, it seems like it should work, but no dice.

Comment: You're assuming that the GUI thread is to blame. Are you sure that your audio stream thread is not acting up? Are you sure that the priority change succeeded? How does the audio thread interface with the gui thread - are you, say, unwittingly forcing priority inversion? I think that as-is, your question lacks sufficient detail. The Qt code is OK. The pthread code is "OK" assuming you check for errors.

Comment: Yes I am checking return values of my pthreads calls and they are all succeeding. I can let my program run endlessly and it streams audio with no xflows, as long as I don't interact with the GUI.  Once I start moving the pointer around the touchscreen, within seconds I get underflows in my audio thread.

Regarding the interface, a socket listens for an incoming message and spawns the audio thread when it is requested to. The same application code runs flawlessly as a CLI app. When I slap the GUI on it I get issues.

Comment: Now that I think about it I wonder if the problem is the device driver for the touchscreen is hogging CPU when I'm using it.  Not sure how I could check that, or how I could prevent it.

Comment: Run your cli app and the audio-less gui app separately. Or simply hang up the GUI thread (sleep in it!) - that guarantees that it's not busy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running under linux, you can create a script and run the script after your application started.

The following sample script uses chrt to changes your Qt app threads priority.

To use the following script, you need to modify the script to change "your_qt_app" name. Also, in the script, I assigned the threads of your_qt_app to use FIFO real-time policy with priority of 10. You can adjust accordingly based on your needs.

Also the "ps" command in the script can help you analyze your system processes/threads priorities.

```
#!/bin/bash
threads_to_change_prio="
    your_qt_app
 "

 ps -Leo pid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,psr,pcpu,stat,wchan:14,comm,args  > ./threads_prio.txt
 for i in $threads_to_change_prio; do
      tids=$(cat ./threads_prio.txt | grep $i | awk '{print $2}');
      for j in $tids; do        
          chrt -f -p 10 $j;
      done
 done
```